# Is it possible to know when a QLPreviewController reaches the end of a document?

Tags: ios, swift, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I use a QLPreviewController to display a pdf file to my users. Everything works well. I just want know when the user reach the end of the document.

Do you know if it's possible ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not, the main issue is there is no nice/clean way to figure out if the scroll position has reached the end of the document. I've tried going through all the controller's subviews to find the UIScrollView instance so I could set it's delegate to my subclassed instance of `QLPreviewController` but it doesn't have one, seems it uses some other UI element to handle the scrolling that is pretty locked down.

You are better off just using the `QLPreviewControllerDelegate` and making use of the `func previewControllerWillDismiss(_ controller: QLPreviewController)` function to detect when the user is finished previewing the document instead of reaching the bottom.